# How can I merge a branch without submodules into a branch with a newly created submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am on `master` in a repository without submodules. I create a new branch `remote` and add and commit some changes there. Then, back on `master`, I convert a subdirectory into a submodule and add and commit some changes within it, and add and commit the submodule commit within the parent repository.

Now I'd like to merge `remote` into `master`. If there are changes pertinent to the submodule, I'd like them to become conflicts within the submodule, and not the parent repo. How can I do this?

Here is a script to reproduce the state described above:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mkdir repo
mkdir repo/a/
mkdir repo/b/
echo 'a' > repo/a/a.txt
echo 'b' > repo/b/b.txt
cd repo
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git checkout -b remote
echo 'c' > b/c.txt
echo 'b' >> b/b.txt
git add .
git commit -m "Changes"
git checkout master
cd ..
git clone repo copy
cd copy
git filter-repo --subdirectory-filter b
cd ..
cd repo
git rm -rf b
git add .
git commit -m "Remove b"
git submodule add ../copy b
git commit -m "Add b as submodule"
echo 'd' > b/d.txt
cd b
git add .
git commit -m "Add new file in submodule b"
cd ..
git add .
git commit -m "Add submodule commit"
```

If I run `git merge remote` after this, I get this output:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    b/b.txt
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
```

Comment: If you've come to this question because you're attempting some sort of repository automation with submodules, just know that after about a year of effort I ended up giving up on using submodules entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If there are changes pertinent to the submodule, I'd like them to become conflicts within the submodule, and not the parent repo.

Considering one branch does *not* have the submodule, while the other does have a submodule, it is best to follow the error advice and `git rm b` first in remote, before trying the `git merge remote`.

Plus, do not forget that branches inside a submodule are distinct from branches inside a parent repository.

Finally:

```bash
echo 'd' > b/d.txt
cd b
git add .
git commit -m "Add new file in submodule b"
cd ..
git add .
git commit -m "Add submodule commit"
```

When you make any change to a submodule, and register the new tree in the parent repository, do not forget to *push* from the submodule to its own upstream repository. Or your parent repository would reflect a submodule repository main tree which ... nobody else will be able to clone and replicate/checkout.

---

After [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253523/discussion-between-vonc-and-lanf), the OP reports having achieve the expected result with:

```bash
# Start the merge procedure.
git status
git submodule deinit --all
git checkout remote
rm -rf /tmp/b
mv b /tmp/b
git add .
git commit -m "Remove b"
git checkout master
git merge --no-edit remote
git submodule sync
git submodule update --init
git status
cd b
git status

# Initialize a new repository with the copied files from remote
cd /tmp/b
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"

# Merge the new repository into the submodule
cd -
git remote add newstuff /tmp/b
git fetch newstuff
git merge --no-edit --allow-unrelated-histories newstuff/master
git status

Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/b/.git/
[master (root-commit) 8b80187] Initial commit
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 b.txt
 create mode 100644 c.txt
/home/mal/ki/repo/b
remote: Enumerating objects: 4, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), 430 bytes | 430.00 KiB/s, done.
From /tmp/b
 * [new branch]      master     -> newstuff/master
Auto-merging b.txt
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in b.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
HEAD detached at 1e097f2
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Changes to be committed:
    new file:   c.txt

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
    both added:      b.txt
```

Comment: If I `git rm b` first, how can I merge the files in `b` into the submodule (so that they become conflicts in the submodule)? Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: @lanf Not "automatically", since b in one branch is a regular folder, and a submodule in the other. You should save and then import those files manually during the first merge. Then make the reverse merge in order to report in both branches b as a submodule. Once b is a submodule in both branches, you can manage merges of b files in the b upstream repository itself: all that the parent repository manages is the submodule root tree SHA1, nothing else.

Comment: Thanks this is extremely helpful! When you say "save and import manually", you mean copy them into the submodule, right? But what if there are unstaged or uncommitted changes in the submodule?

Comment: @lanf You can copy them in a separate folder, outside any Git repository, and, from the b folder being merged, do a `git --work-tree=/path/to/outside/save_folder add .`: that will detect any change/addition/removal of those b files, compared to the current b local repository (used as submodule in your case).

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand exactly what you are telling me to do, but I cannot even checkout my remote branch in order to "save and import those files manually". Git says I would be overwriting untracked working tree files.

Comment: @lanf you need a clean working tree indeed. Make sure git status is clean, or add/commit first.

Comment: It is clean, when I `git status`, it says `working tree clean`. But I see `error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        b/b.txt`. Note that `b` is the submodule.

Comment: The working tree is clean within the submodule as well.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the error message. You said it's telling me to `git rm b` in the remote, but it seems like it might mean on `master`. Because `b` is definitely tracked on `remote`, but it's a submodule on `master`.

Comment: @lanf True, you need to `git rm b` (no trailing slash) and `git commit` in `master`, before attempting the `git merge remote`

Comment: Okay, and then I will merge remote, which will essentially overwrite `b` on `master`, because the submodule is gone now, and so how do I actually merge the remote `b` files into the `master` `b` files, which I've now destroyed?

Comment: @lanf The remote branch has a regular b folder which will be merged, with its content, to master.

Comment: Yes but you've told me to `git rm b` prior to this merge. So it doesn't seem like anything useful is actually happening in `b`. We've just wholemeal replaced the files that were in `master` with the files that were in `remote`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253523/discussion-between-vonc-and-lanf).